# Amount of text within a paragraph tag is pushing other elements when resizing the window

Tags: html, css

Three divs are displayed inline and each has an img, h, p and a tags. The problem is, under each image within the div there is a different amount of text. Example: When you start resizing the window, under the first two divs, the text is displayed in 4 rows, but the text for the 3rd div is displayed into 5 rows and it pushes the image and heading upwards, making it visually a mess. This happens a couple of more times at random window sizes, as the amount of text directly affects the positions of the other elements. Any help?

I've tried wrapping the pargraph tag within another div to which I would give a class and give it a certain height through css, but it didn't really help much. The span-1-of-3 class is part of a separate css file, a grid I've found online.

```
<div class="span-1-of-3 box">
                <h3>New Products</h3>
                    <img src="img/girlleather.jpeg" alt="Woman in Leather" class="what-img">
                    <div class="text-box"><p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p></div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Check out</a>       
            </div>
            <div class="span-1-of-3 box">
                <h3>Fashion Show</h3>
                    <img src="img/fashionshow.jpeg" alt="Fashion Show" class="what-img">
                    <div class="text-box"><p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p></div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Check out</a>       
            </div>
            <div class="span-1-of-3 box">
                <h3>New: Watches</h3>
                    <img src="img/watches.jpg" alt="Watches" class="what-img">
                    <div class="text-box"><p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p></div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Check out</a>       
            </div>

.what-img {
    width: 94%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.new {
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.box h3 {
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.box p {
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.text-box {
   position: relative;
}

.box a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
   background-color: #923d0a;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   border-radius: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 20px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Comment: can you please post the css part also ?

Comment: How do they displayed inline? It looks like they just come one after another

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the attribute vertical-align can help you:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
.what-img {
    width: 94%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.new {
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -20px;
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.box h3 {
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.box p {
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.text-box {
   position: relative;
}

.box a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
   background-color: #923d0a;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   border-radius: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 20px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="span-1-of-3 box">
  <h3>New Products</h3>
  <img src="img/girlleather.jpeg" alt="Woman in Leather" class="what-img">
  <div class="text-box"><p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p></div>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Check out</a>       
</div>
<div class="span-1-of-3 box">
  <h3>Fashion Show</h3>
  <img src="img/fashionshow.jpeg" alt="Fashion Show" class="what-img">
  <div class="text-box"><p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p></div>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Check out</a>       
</div>
<div class="span-1-of-3 box">
  <h3>New: Watches</h3>
  <img src="img/watches.jpg" alt="Watches" class="what-img">
  <div class="text-box"><p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p></div>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Check out</a>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I did was to wrap it all with a `div` with `flex` as a row and set a **fixed width** (1000px for example).

Then in the `.box` css I added a `max-width` property, also with a fixed max-with of 333px (1000 for the container divided to 3 divs: 1000 / 3 = 333).

Because I'm using a fixed width, even if you resize the window it won't effect the space everything is taking and won't make it messy like before.

```css
.inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 1000px
}

.what-img {
  width: 94%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.new {
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -20px;
  max-width: 333px;
}

.box h3 {
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.box p {
  padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.text-box {
  position: relative;
}

.box a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  background-color: #923d0a;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
  <div class="span-1-of-3 box">
    <h3>New Products</h3>
    <img src="img/girlleather.jpeg" alt="Woman in Leather" class="what-img">
    <div class="text-box">
      <p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Check out</a>
  </div>
  <div class="span-1-of-3 box">
    <h3>Fashion Show</h3>
    <img src="img/fashionshow.jpeg" alt="Fashion Show" class="what-img">
    <div class="text-box">
      <p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Check out</a>
  </div>
  <div class="span-1-of-3 box">
    <h3>New: Watches</h3>
    <img src="img/watches.jpg" alt="Watches" class="what-img">
    <div class="text-box">
      <p>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Check out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```